# Google Desktop Search stopped indexing my outlook email after upgrading Outlook 2003 to Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, google-desktop-search

I can't seem to find any of the emails that should have been indexed after installing 2010.
Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I am reading that GDT will no longer index ANY emails in Outlook2010.  MS seems to have disabled access.

There are a few posts in MS tech support that appeared with the beta release- and the mods/forum seem to be happy with murky info that appears to blame other sources- they then lock the question, call it answered and move on.

Elsewhere you can read that MS has eliminated this function, requiring you to use the Windows search.

Google Desktop are total wienies in that they don't discuss this as a 'known issue'.

Very frustrated